# Bug in TensorFlow reduce_max for negative infinity?

Tags: python, tensorflow

Using `tf.maximum` with negative inf inputs as follows:

```
tf.maximum(-math.inf, -math.inf).eval()
```

gives the expected result `-inf`

However, `tf.reduce_max`, on the same inputs:

```
tf.reduce_max([-math.inf, -math.inf]).eval()
```

gives: `-3.40282e+38` which is the min float32.

For positive infinity inputs, both functions result in `inf`. Is this a bug?

Comment: This looks like a bug to me. Can you file a bug on github?

Comment: Did that already, just forgot to post here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This turned out to be a bug in Eigen which has already been fixed and pushed out to TensorFlow.

The issue can be tracked here:
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/4131